# How to add SwaggerUI when mapping a FallbackRoute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger-ui, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I´m having an ASP.NET Core project where I combine some WebApi controllers and I serve a SPA (created in ELM) through the Index.html file.
I added [Swagger](https://swagger.io/) for debugging reasons.

The goal should be to have routes like that:
• `/events` -> mapped to a SignalR Hub
• `/api/*` -> mapped to web api controllers
• `/hangfire` -> showing the [Hangfire Dashboard](https://www.hangfire.io/)
• `/swagger` -> showing the swagger UI
• anything else -> returning `Index.html`

I got everything running except the swagger UI.

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    ...

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Swagger API V1");
    });

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapHub<EventsHub>("/events");
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions
        {
            Authorization = new[] { new AllowAnyoneAuthorizationFilter() },
            IsReadOnlyFunc = _ => true
        });
        endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
    });
}
```

The reason is that the `MapFallbackToFile()` route has a higher priority than the `SwaggerEndpoint()` route.
When I remove the `MapFallbackToFile()` route swagger is working again but then all the client routes don´t work anymore.

Can anybody tell me how to add swagger to the endpoint configuration?
Thank you! :)

## Update 1 - add ConfigureServices method

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(AllowAnyOrigin, builder =>
        {
            builder
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader();
        });
    });

    services.AddControllers()
    services.AddMvc().AddControllersAsServices();

    services.AddSignalR();
    services.AddOptions();

    ... // Custom services

    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Swagger API", Version = "v1" });
    });

    services.AddHangfire(config => config
        .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
        .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
        .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
        .UseSqlServerStorage(Configuration.GetConnectionString("HangfireConnection"), new SqlServerStorageOptions
        {
            CommandBatchMaxTimeout = 60.Seconds(),
            SlidingInvisibilityTimeout = 60.Seconds(),
            QueuePollInterval = 60.Seconds(),
            UseRecommendedIsolationLevel = true,
            UsePageLocksOnDequeue = true,
            DisableGlobalLocks = true
        }));
    services.AddHangfireServer();
}
```